# How to make a Multithread Application using Hazelcast

Tags: java, multithreading, queue, pool, hazelcast

I am trying to develop a project for my graduation project. I am using free version of Hazelcast so i couldn't ask support for help.

I wrote a java application that works on single computer. I am using LinkedList for queue, and have a pool of 5 worker threads. Worker threads just take one of the job from queue and executes it.

Code for the job:

```
package com.stackoverflow.multithread.app;

import java.util.Date;

/**
 * Job
 */
public class Job implements Runnable {

    private final Object req;
    private final long createTime = new Date().getTime();

    public Job(Object req) {
        this.req = req;
    }

    public boolean isPoison() {
        return req == null;
    }

    public long getWaitTime(){
        return new Date().getTime() - createTime;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
             //Do the job
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Code for the Work Queue

```
package com.stackoverflow.multithread.app;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * WorkQueue
 */
public class WorkQueue {

    private static int minThreads;
    private static int maxThreads;
    private static final List<PoolWorker> threads = new ArrayList<PoolWorker>();
    private static final LinkedList queue = new LinkedList();
    private static WorkQueue instance = null;

    /**
     * WorkQueue
     */
    protected WorkQueue() {
        minThreads = 1;
        maxThreads = 5;

        for (int i = 0; i < minThreads; i++) {
            PoolWorker worker = new PoolWorker();
            threads.add(worker);
            worker.start();
        }
    }

    /**
     * getInstance
     *
     * @return Singleton WorkQueue instance
     */
    public static WorkQueue getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new WorkQueue();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    /**
     * clone
     *
     * @return null
     * @throws CloneNotSupportedException: Singleton class can not be cloned.
     */
    @Override
    public WorkQueue clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        throw new CloneNotSupportedException("Singleton class can not be cloned.");
    }

    public void execute(Job r) {
        synchronized (queue) {
            queue.addLast(r);
            manageWorkers();
            queue.notify();
        }
    }

    private void manageWorkers(){
        while ((queue.size() / 2 > threads.size() || (queue.size() > 0 && ((Job)queue.peekFirst()).getWaitTime() > 1000)) && threads.size() < maxThreads){
            PoolWorker worker = new PoolWorker();
            threads.add(worker);
            worker.start();
        }
        if (queue.size() < threads.size() && threads.size() > minThreads){
            execute(new Job(null)); //poison
        }
    }

    private class PoolWorker extends Thread {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Job r;

            while (true) {
                synchronized (queue) {
                    while (queue.isEmpty()) {
                        try {
                            queue.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
                        }
                    }

                    r = (Job) queue.removeFirst();
                    manageWorkers();
                    if (r.isPoison()) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                // If we don't catch RuntimeException, 
                // the pool could leak threads
                try {
                    r.run();
                } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ExceptionInInitializerError e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
            }
            threads.remove(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Now i want to make this work on an **active-active cluster** and want to use HazelCast (v3.3), to ensure that **each and all the jobs should be executed exactly once**, even if one of the computers is down.

I checked ExecutorService yet it executes the jobs one by one (single thread). I couldn't find a good solution to do this. People mention ParallelExecutorService yet it is either not usable in this version, or it is not part of free edition.

Please note that I don't have to do this using Hazelcast. Any free solution is fine by me.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make use of the IExecutorService, which implements the Executor(Service) interface. So you can just throw a task in there (make sure it is serializable) and any member in the cluster can take that task to process it.

No need to mess around with your own threadpools.

Here are set of examples you can have a look at:
https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/distributed-executor